# Grab.app disappearing from dock?

Tags: macos

When I use Grab, if ever I close all its windows and then take focus away from it by clicking somewhere else it disappears from the dock.

Grab hides from the dock even if the Grab window I close is the "About Grab" window. Grab doesn't hide from the dock if I open it and then take away focus *before* opening and closing a Grab window.

I can see the Grab process is still running when I check from Terminal and when I "reopen" it to get it back into the dock it's the same PID and only one copy is running.

Does anyone know how to stop Grab from hiding? I don't want Grab permanently in the dock even when it's closed, I just want it to stop hiding while I'm using it. I'm using MacOS 10.10.5 MBP 11,3.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "Automatic Termination" and is also implemented for QuickTime Player and others.  The processes stay open in the background, so they re-open quickly, but with enough memory pressure (for other processes or applications for example) they will be forced to terminate.

To disable it, open Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities, or search via Spotlight) and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.Grab NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool yes
```

Then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. 
Make sure to properly quit and relaunch Grab after running this defaults write command.

To restore the original settings, run the following command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Grab NSDisableAutomaticTermination
```

From the Apple Developers site:

> Automatic and Sudden Termination of Apps Improve the User Experience
>   In OS X v10.7 and later, the use of the Quit command to terminate an
>   app is diminished in favor of more user-centric techniques.
>   Specifically, Cocoa supports two techniques that make the termination
>   of an app transparent and fast:
>
> Automatic termination eliminates the need for users to quit an app.
>   Instead, the system manages app termination transparently behind the
>   scenes, terminating apps that are not in use to reclaim needed
>   resources such as memory. Sudden termination allows the system to kill
>   an app’s process immediately without waiting for it to perform any
>   final actions. The system uses this technique to improve the speed of
>   operations such as logging out of, restarting, or shutting down the
>   computer. Automatic termination and sudden termination are independent
>   techniques, although both are designed to improve the user experience
>   of app termination. Although Apple recommends that apps support both,
>   an app can support one technique and not the other. Apps that support
>   both techniques can be terminated by the system without the app being
>   involved at all. On the other hand, if an app supports sudden
>   termination but not automatic termination, then it must be sent a Quit
>   event, which it needs to process without displaying any user interface
>   dialogs.
>
> Automatic termination transfers the job of managing processes from the
>   user to the system, which is better equipped to handle the job. Users
>   do not need to manage processes manually anyway. All they really need
>   is to run apps and have those apps available when they need them.
>   Automatic termination makes that possible while ensuring that system
>   performance is not adversely affected.
>
> Apps must opt in to both automatic termination and sudden termination
>   and implement appropriate support for them. In both cases, the app
>   must ensure that any user data is saved well before termination can
>   happen. And because the user does not quit an autoterminable app, such
>   an app should also save the state of its user interface using the
>   built-in Cocoa support. Saving and restoring the interface state
>   provides the user with a sense of continuity between app launches.
>
> For information on how to support for automatic termination in your
>   app, see Automatic Termination. For information on how to support
>   sudden termination, see Sudden Termination.

[Automatic and Sudden Termination of Apps Improve the User Experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW22)